# Q: Optional use of 'the' referring to "daily life of" vs. "daily life as"

Tags: definite-articles

Helping a recent graduate with a cover letter and ran into an interesting question about 'the'.  Please consider these two passages:

> ... As a result, I have a better understanding of both the demanding
> and rewarding aspects **of daily life as** an engineer and have confidence
> in this career path ...
>
> ... As a result, I have a better understanding of ... aspects **of the daily life of** an engineer and have confidence ...

We couldn't decide which was better "... of daily life as ..." vs. "... of the daily life as ..."

Is there a rule of grammar or usage that makes one correct vs. incorrect?  Or is it just a matter of preference?

Thanks!